# Unable to to update yt-dlp using pip command

Tags: python, python-3.x, yt-dlp

I am unable to update yt-dlp on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 -  hopefully someone can help me.

My details are:

```
[debug] Command-line config: ['-v']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, pref UTF-8, out utf-8, error utf-8, screen utf-8
[debug] yt-dlp version 2023.01.06 [6becd25] (pip)
[debug] Python 3.11.1 (CPython arm64 64bit) - macOS-13.2.1-arm64-arm-64bit (OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023)
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 5.1.2 (setts), ffprobe 5.1.2
[debug] Optional libraries: Cryptodome-3.16.0, brotli-1.0.9, certifi-2022.12.07, mutagen-1.46.0, sqlite3-2.6.0, websockets-10.4
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[debug] Loaded 1760 extractors
```

If I type python3 --version I get:

```
Python 3.9.6
```

I installed yt-dlp using pip, so when I try to update in the normal way I'm getting these messages:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: yt-dlp in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (2023.2.17)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (3.17)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.46.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (2022.12.7)
```

My pip3 version is:

```
pip 23.0.1 from /Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

​

I am the only user of the machine and am on the admin account.  I tried logging out and back in again and it still won't update.   I'm not sure what the problem is, but any help would be most welcome.

I am unable to update yt-dlp on MacOS and hopefully someone can help me.

My details are:

```
[debug] Command-line config: ['-v']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, pref UTF-8, out utf-8, error utf-8, screen utf-8
[debug] yt-dlp version 2023.01.06 [6becd25] (pip)
[debug] Python 3.11.1 (CPython arm64 64bit) - macOS-13.2.1-arm64-arm-64bit (OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023)
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 5.1.2 (setts), ffprobe 5.1.2
[debug] Optional libraries: Cryptodome-3.16.0, brotli-1.0.9, certifi-2022.12.07, mutagen-1.46.0, sqlite3-2.6.0, websockets-10.4
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[debug] Loaded 1760 extractors
```

If I type python3 --version I get:

```
Python 3.9.6
```

I installed yt-dlp using pip, so I try to update yt-dlp using this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade yt-dlp
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: yt-dlp in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (2023.2.17)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodomex in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (3.17)
Requirement already satisfied: mutagen in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (1.46.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from yt-dlp) (2022.12.7)
```

My pip3 version is:

```
pip 23.0.1 from /Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

​

I am the only user of the machine and am on the admin account.  I tried logging out and back in again and it still won't update.   I'm not sure what the problem is, but any help would be most welcome.